# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: cb is not a function in loopback.js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have the following code:

**Orders.js**

```
'use strict';

var OrderService = require('../services/OrderService');

module.exports = function(Orders) {

    var orderService = new OrderService(Orders);

    Orders.history = function(data, cb) {
        console.log("getting history");
        orderService.getHistory(data, cb)
            .catch(err => cb(err));
    };

    Orders.remoteMethod('history', {
        http: { verb: 'get', path: '/:token/history' },
        accepts: [
            { arg: "token", type: "string", required: true },
            { arg: "base_token", type: "string", required: true }
        ],
        returns: { type: 'object', root: true }
    });

};
```

**Orderservice.js**

```
function OrderService(Orders){
}

OrderService.prototype.getHistory = async function(token, baseToken,  callback){

    <some operation>

    callback(null, this.validatorService.finalize(buyResult));
}
```

When I hit this API, I get the following error

```
node:1996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: cb is not a function
   at orderService.getHistory.catch.err (/usr/app/server/models/orders.js:12:18)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
 (node:1996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
| (node:1996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have similar code for other models and services, what am I missing?

Comment: I'd start by logging `cb` inside `Orders.history` to see what it is, and check what's calling it

Comment: There are two parmaters that need to be passed, cb should be the third one. Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: Hi @user3288346, was the answer below useful?

Answer (score 4):

When you define a remoteMethod the amount of arguments must always be equal to a number of arguments defined in the `accepts` property of your remoteMethod plus one which is `cb`. In your case there are two arguments defined in the `accepts` property, so the function should look like:

```
Orders.history = function(token, base_token, cb) {
    console.log("getting history");
    orderService.getHistory(token, cb)
        .catch(err => cb(err));
};
```

I would also recommend you to change your Orders.history to an async function and move away from callbacks completely. [Loopback supports async functions/promises](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-promises.html) starting from version 2. The function can be defined as following:

```
Orders.history = async function(token, base_token) {
    console.log("getting history");
    return orderService.getHistory(token); // must return a promise
};
```

It may require a bit of code refactoring on your side but it allows you to write a cleaner code and you do not have to worry about the exceptions handling all the time (Loopback supports it out of the box for async functions).